# Formula para crear fechas con case_when

Tags: formulas

Como puede usar la formula case_when para crear fechas,

wdsf%>% mutate(year=case_when(year >1950,year==1960)

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. te sugiero que uses las etiquetas apropiadas (esto parece R) y que digas lo que esperas obtener.